# Rewriting code with an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file X_true that consists of sentences like these:

```
evid emerg interview show done deal 
munich hamburg train crash wednesday first gener ice model power two electr power locomot capac 759 passeng 
one report earlier week said older two boy upset girlfriend broken polic confirm 
jordan previous said
```

Now instead of storing these sentences in a file, I wish to put them in an array(List of strings) to work with them throughout the code. So the array would look something like this:

```
 ['evid emerg interview show done deal', 
'munich hamburg train crash wednesday first gener ice model power two electr power locomot capac 759 passeng', 
'one report earlier week said older two boy upset girlfriend broken polic confirm', 
'jordan previous said']
```

Earlier when working with the file, this was the code I was using:

```
def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output
row = run('cat '+'/Users/mink/X_true.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
```

Now when I working with *X_true* as an array, how can I write an equivalent statement for the *row* assignment above?

Comment: what does the "array" look like?  Is it a list of strings?  Do you want to consider each string it's own line?  If yes, then wouldn't it be more efficient to get the length of the list instead of farming the work out to `wc`?

Comment: Why are you doing a split on integer value?

Comment: Let me guess: You want a function to give you the line count of a file?

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, it is giving me the count of the file. *X_true* consists of a list of strings. Earlier I was using a file and then getting the line count. However now I wish to completely remove processing the file and use *X_true* as an array instead. So how do I write an equivalent function for it?

Comment: @CoderQueen `len(X_true)` gives you the length of the list. What do you want exactly? Nobody can help you if you're not precise in your question. Give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You have to carefully look at what each function is doing, eg. `run(...)` runs some program, and that is not needed when you already have the content of the file. Note also that you can easily get the word count of a file without running external programs (your first program is roughly equivalent to `open('/Users/mink/X_true.txt').read().count('\n')`)

Comment: @L3viathan I have edited the question and provided some more details.

Answer (score 1):

len(X_true_array) ,where X_true_array is the array of ur file content represented by array.

because before then u use wc -l to get the line count of ur file,and in here u can represent the line count through the count of array item.

Answer (score 1):

So I understand this correctly, you just want to read in a file and store each line as an element of an array?

```
X_true = []
with open("X_true.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        X_true.append(line.strip())
```

Another option (thanks @roeland):

```
with open("X_true.txt") as f:
    X_true = list(map(str.strip, f))
```

Comment: I think you can write `X_true = list(f)` instead of that loop.

Comment: @roeland Then you'll have to use `map` or something like that to get rid of the `\n`s, but yes, good point.

Comment: This is a great answer. To go a little further, let's say OP wants python to break up a string rather than doing it from a file (which would be the wrong choice).

You would use `my_string.split("\n")`, or whatever is breaking up the sentences you want to store. If I wanted to split up a sentence into words, I would do it like this: `hello world.split(" ")` 

which returns:

`["hello", "world]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Using `readlines`

```
X_true = open("x_true.txt").readlines()
```

Using `read`:

```
X_true = open("x_true.txt").read().split("\n")
```

Using `List comprehension`:

```
X_true = [line.rstrip() for line in open("x_true.txt")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(X_true.txt) as f:
    X_true= f.readlines()
```

or with stripping the newline character:

```
X_true= [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(X_true.txt)]
```

Refer [Input and Ouput:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(X_true.txt) as f:  
    array_of_lines = f.readlines()
```

array_of_lines will look like your example above.  Note: it will still have the newline characters at the end of each string in the array.  Those can be removed with string.strip() if they're a concern.